# Is there a way to rearrange styled-components css in alphabetical order?

Tags: phpstorm, webstorm, styled-components

WebStorm offers the setting `Sort CSS properties` - `By name`.

**Which rearranges:**

```
.test {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

**to:**

```
.test {
    align-items: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: flex;
}
```

Sadly, this does not apply to the `styled-components` CSS:

```js
const StyledComponent = styled.div`
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    cursor: pointer;
`;
```

Is there a way to achieve the exact same behaviour for the CSS in JS part of the styled-components in WebStorm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not supported currently, see https://github.com/styled-components/webstorm-styled-components/issues/60. Related youtrack ticket: [WEB-28540](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-28540)